# привести массив к нужной форме

Tags: php, ajax

У меня на input весит обработчик с отправкой AJAX на сервер вот такого вида

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#textbox2').bind("change past keyup", function(){

            var lenght = $('#textbox2').val().length;
            if(lenght >= 3) 
            {
                var val = $('#textbox2').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/auth/search',
                    data: val,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('.results').html(data);
                    }
                });
            } 

        });

    });
```

Отправляет запрос если в input равно или больше  3-х символов

На стороне сервера код к которому обращаемся выглядит очень просто

```
 var_dump($_POST);
 exit();
```

Если я ввожу в input например "Привет мир"
у меня выводится вот такая строка

```
    array(1) { ["Привет_мир"] => string(0) "" }
```

Как видите нужное значение стало ключём массива а не его  значением.
Как мне преобразовать массив к нормальному виду?

Желательно :

```
     array(1) { [0] => string(10) "Привет мир" }
```

Так же желательно сделать это до отправки на сервер(если так можно), а не на стороне PHP

Comment: ajax-> `data: { paramName: val }`, получите `$_POST['paramName] == val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно отправляют пары `ключ(параметр)-значение`, вы же отправляете просто строку, которая становится именем параметра с пустым значением.

При отправке вам слеует поименовать параметр, и указать его значение, поэтому вызове `$.post` следует сделать примерно так:

```
....
data: { myParam: val },
....
```

Тогда на стороне сервера вы получите `$_POST['myParam']` c вашим значением `val`