# Как привести массив к нужному виду?

Tags: python, java, c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Ответ на [этой странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763445/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5) для меня немного сложноват, нужно алгоритм простыми словами :)

**Входные данные:**
1 поправил подвёз 1 3 переместил

**Из этой строки нужно сделать пары ключ-значение:**

поправил: 1, подвез: 1, переместил: 3.

**Как это сделать?**

Предполагаю, что надо сделать из строки массив слов, например методом `string.split()` в python (приветствуются также примеры на C++ и Java), затем отсортировать массив в порядке "слово, число, слово, число..." (как это сделать пока не знаю), а потом просто достать из этого массива пары. Нужен алгоритм сортировки или другой метод решения задачи.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого и подобных случаев можно так, например:

```py
a = "1 поправил подвёз 1 3 переместил"

words = []
numbers = []
_ = [numbers.append(int(x)) if x.isdigit() else words.append(x) for x in a.split()]
res = dict(zip(words, numbers))
print(res)
```

> {'поправил': 1, 'подвёз': 1, 'переместил': 3}

либо, то же самое, но короче:

```py
a = "1 поправил подвёз 1 3 переместил"
res = dict(zip((x for x in a.split() if not x.isdigit()),
                (x for x in a.split() if x.isdigit())))
```